# How to calculate sum of amount for each 5 weeks before in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am having the amount field in income table in database, as well as the created date in same table. I need data like,

```
Week 1 => Sum(amount for week 1)
Week 2 => Sum(amount for week 2)
Week 3 => Sum(amount for week 3)
Week 4 => Sum(amount for week 4)
Week 5 => Sum(amount for week 5)
```

What should be my linq query. I am using entity framework.
**Edited:**
Say previous 4 week of current week + current week =5 weeks. here current week is the week of today's date. eg. today is 26'th Aug 2014 so current week is from 24'th Aug 2014 **(Sunday)** **to** 30'th Aug 2014 **(Saturday)**.

Comment: What do you mean by "week 1" exactly? The first seven days of each month? Or the first seven days starting from the first Monday? Or something else? What if there's data spanning more than 5 weeks? This question doesn't have enough information to answer at the moment.

Comment: I mean previous 5 weeks including current week.

Comment: And what do you mean by "current week", *exactly*? The question is *still* very unclear.

Comment: @RedSwan: Not necessarily. In some countries, the week starts on Sunday, not on Monday. Granted, this may not be the default in most countries, but perhaps it's still good to make sure what exactly the OP meant.

Comment: @Stakx, Agree...consider 7 days as week from sunday to saturday.

Comment: @RedSwan: It's not a matter of how many days are in the week, it's when it starts. Most people in the UK would think of a week as being Monday to Sunday, for example... although a Christian church would take a different approach. This is *not* a matter of "oh come on" - it's a matter of providing precise requirements, understanding that the world is a complicated place with different cultures and contexts involved.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Pardon me. I cleared my question please read edited part.

Comment: Again, it would be clearer if you'd specifically say that you were interested in a Sunday-based week. (Yes, the example implies it, but it would be best to be clear.)

Comment: Please check, is that cleared ?

Comment: I think some code would be useful for providing a working answer.  Like an entity model with a datetime and an amount property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the methods in [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform date and time arithmetic. So you should *start* by working out the start and end dates, then use `TruncateTime` if necessary to truncate your created date to a date (instead of date and time), and use `DiffDays` to work out "number of days since the start of the period". Then just divide by 7 to group...

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime start = today.AddDays(-(int) today.DayOfWeek) // Sunday...
                      .AddDays(-28);                   // 4 weeks ago
DateTime end = start.AddDays(7 * 5);

var result = from entry in db.Entries
             where entry.Created >= start && entry.Created < end
             group entry.Amount by EntityFunctions.DiffDays(start, 
                 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(entry.Created)) / 7 into g
             select new { Week = g.Key + 1, Sum = g.Sum() };
```

While I'd *expect* that to work, I haven't personally done any date/time work in EF myself. The general approach should be fine, it's just that you may need to tweak it. Also note that this *won't* give you any results for weeks that don't have any entries - it's probably easiest to do that outside EF.

EDIT: If the summing part isn't working, it's easy to do the summing locally instead:

```
var query = from entry in db.Entries
             where entry.Created >= start && entry.Created < end
             group entry.Amount by EntityFunctions.DiffDays(start, 
                 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(entry.Created)) / 7;

var result = query.AsEnumerable() // Execute the rest locally
                  .Select(g => new { Week = g.Key + 1, Sum = g.Sum() });
```

Comment: Thanks for help. where  g.Sum() does not support or resolved. perhaps you are right about entity framework.

Comment: @RedSwan: See my edit... although it's not clear exactly what's wrong. (It would help if you could give the *exact* error message.)

Comment: Error 1 'System.Linq.IGrouping<int?,string>' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Sum(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<decimal?>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Error 2 : Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IGrouping<int?,string>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<decimal?>'

Comment: @RedSwan: That sounds like your `Amount` property is a string... that would certainly cause issues.

Comment: Right. I modified to var result = from entry in db.Entries
             where entry.Created >= start && entry.Created < end
             group Convert.ToDecimal(entry.Amount) by EntityFunctions.DiffDays(start, 
                 EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(entry.Created)) / 7 into g
             select new { Week = g.Key + 1, Sum = g.Sum() }; but getting exception "This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities" at EntityFunctions.TruncateTime

Comment: Can I iterate result ?

Comment: @RedSwan: Well what is `db.Entries`? That's mean to be your EF query to get your entities...

Comment: absolutely right but I am getting exception ""This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities" while running this code

Comment: @RedSwan: What is the *compile-time* type of `db.Entries`? What does the stack trace look like? And why is your `Amount` property not already a `decimal`? (It sounds like you should fix your schema.)

Comment: I am working in existing code, so probably I cannot make changes in schema. whereas db.Entries is of  IEnumerable<Expense> type. Expense is the entity.

Comment: @RedSwan: Well that's the problem - if it's `IEnumerable<Expense>` then you're using `Enumerable` instead of `Queryable`. You need to be working with an expression of type `IQueryable<Expense>` if you want to do all of this in the database. (You *could* pull everything locally, but that sounds like a bad idea to me...)

Comment: omg @JonSkeet you must take money for this 24/7 support here in SO because the God of C# himself providing so brilliant support in as many questions as he can!!

Comment: @Neel, I would say God helps those who does the efforts :) isn't it... Thanks God (@JonSkeet)...I am learning from direct God which is precious for me :)